# python return equal where the string is not actually equal?

Tags: python

I have two strings like `s1='fly,dream';s2='dream,fly'`
I want the `s1` equals to `s2`.

The code I tried is:

```
def Isequal(m,n):
    s1=m.split(',')    s2=n.split(',')   s1.sort()   s2.sort()
    if s1 == s2:
        print 'Equal'
    else:
        print s1,s2
```

Note:s1 may be equal to s2.
Then

```
def Isequal(m,n):
s1=m.split(',')
s2=n.split(',')
if s1 == s2.reverse() || s1 == s2:
print 'Equal'
else:
print s1,s2
```

Is this code right? I there something to improve?

Comment: Is s1 equal to itself or are they only Isequal if the second is the "reverse" of the first?

Comment: You need to define what "equals" means in this case.  I can think of many different definitions that satisfy the single example you gave.  I'm guessing that you want the lists to be equal if they contain the same comma-delimited terms, is that correct?

Comment: Perhaps I'm being snarky but if you want `s1` to equal `s2`, you can just do `s1 = s2`. Then they will be equal. (I think you wanted to know if the order of the words, separated by commas, of each string is the inverse of the other.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code splits the two strings by `,` (which returns a `list`) and calls the `sort` method on the `list`. Since the two substrings are identical, sorting the list of the substrings results in equal lists. The best way to know what is happening is printing the stuff out. See the results.

```
>>> s1 = 'fly,dream'
>>> s2 = 'dream,fly'
>>> s1 = s1.split(',')
>>> s1
['fly', 'dream']
>>> s2 = s2.split(',')
>>> s2
['dream', 'fly']
>>> s1.sort()
>>> s1
['dream', 'fly']
>>> s2.sort()
>>> s2
['dream', 'fly']
>>> s1 == s2
True
```

If you want to check that the two strings consist of the same substrings, use `sets`, like follows :

```
>>> varOne = set(s1.split(','))
>>> varTwo = set(s2.split(','))
>>> varOne == varTwo
True
```

**Beware** that sets only allow unique items, so `fly,dream,fly` and `dream,dream,fly` will result in `True` here.

Answer (score 3):

Set would be more elegant here:

```
def Isequal(m, n):
    s1 = set(m.split(','))
    s2 = set(n.split(','))
    if s1 == s2:
        print 'Equal'
    else:
        print s1, s2
```

and should be more efficient too.

Comment: Depends on whether "dream,fly,dream" should be 'equal' to "dream,fly".

Comment: You may be right @tobias_k, so +1 for your comment. Equality isn't defined well in this question. I've assumed that if ordering is irrelevant then multiple occurrences too.

Comment: Agreed, but you could extend your answer by your "interpretation" of the equality criterion. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to use `sort()` to flip a list. The sorting that takes place entirely depends on the string (it varies on the first letter of each string). You can use `.reverse` to reverse a list:

```
def Isequal(m,n):
    m = m.split(',')
    m.reverse()
    if m == n.split(','):
        print "Equal"
    else:
        print m, n
```

If you want to sort the list in place, you can always do `.reverse()` instead of `.sort()`

---

If reversing the list was just an example in your question, and your strings would actually have more items when you split them, you can use sets:

```
def Isequal(m,n):
    if not set(m.split(',')).symmetric_difference(n.split(',')):
        print "Equal"
    else:
        print m, n
```

---

By the way, `Sparse is better than dense.`. The semi-colons are rather... ugly.

Comment: That works for this specific example, but I think he's looking at a more general problem: having two strings composed of keywords separated by commas, how do you say they're the same set?  I think putting them in a set is probably more useful, if you don't care about repeats.

Comment: @jszakmeister I've added this is to my answer. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. :-)

Comment: Alternatively: `not set(m.split(',')).symmetric_diffeence(n.split(','))`

Comment: Doesn't `reversed` return a reverse iterator?

Comment: @user2357112 heh, yes it does. Fixed